# Select a same field from a list of similar nested fields in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema.

```
const placeSchema = new Schema({
    description: {
      fr: String,
      en: String,
    },
    comment: {
      fr: String,
      en: String,
    },
    ...
    ...
});

const Place= mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema);

module.exports = Place;
```

If I want to get only 'en' value I am currently using

`await Place.find({}, '-description.fr -comment.fr ...')`

If the number of similar fields increases so does the length of the query. Is there a way to select all the similar fields like maybe *$field*.fr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes there is a way. using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and doing some structure manipulation.

It would look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} //match your document.
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      rootArr: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$rootArr"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "rootArr.v.en": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$rootArr.k",
          v: "$rootArr.v.en"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UJehHwUngtm)

It's a little "hacky" thought, how strict are your schema needs?
Have you considered building it under the following structure?:

```
const placeSchema = new Schema({
    data: [
        {
            lang: String,
            description: String,
            comment: String,
            ...
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I will switch to this schema as it does seem better and works for me. But will nested fields such as, let's say:
`impression: { remarks: String, rating: Number }` 
be problematic, if I want the ratings for all the data to be same.

Comment: At the end of the day you know best how you use your data, and you should try to find the best structure that will make your life easy. nested fields in an array can be a pain sometimes but Mongo offers many tools to handle them. for example [arrayFilters][https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/] makes updating these arrays real easy.

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregation will check all the *top level* fields for a subfield `en`. If it's truthy (should work if you strictly have string values for the language properties), the subfield will be `{ field: { en: fieldValue.en } }` otherwise it will be `{ field: fieldValue }`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
            in: {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                $cond: [
                  "$$this.v.en", // works for string values, otherwise you will have to check more explicitly
                  {
                    en: "$$this.v.en"
                  },
                  "$$this.v"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mVQfuvqkXQR)

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers above are exactly what the question was looking for. This might be a more 'hacky' way of doing things.

First create a function that generates the query string `'-description.fr -comment.fr ...'`

```
let select = '';
const selectLanguage = (fields, lang) => {
   switch (true) {
        case lang === 'fr':
            fields.forEach(field => {
                select= `${select} -${field}.en `;
            });
            break;
        case lang === 'en':
            fields.forEach(field => {
                select = `${select} -${field}.fr `;
            });
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
    
    return select;
}
```

This generates a string like `' -fieldName1.fr -fieldName2.fr ..'` for english and and `' -fieldName1.en ..'` for french. Then we can use this statement in the query above.

```
const select = selectLanguage(['description', 'comment', ..], 'en')

await Place.find({}, select)   //await Place.find({}, ' -description.fr -comment.fr ..')
```